# Align text in spans to the bottom of Angular Material icons with CSS?

Tags: html, css, angular-material

I have the following bit of code. I want to make the text in the spans line up with the bottom of the stars.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="starCount">
    <span>Not Relevant</span>
    <button
        mat-icon-button
        color="primary"
        *ngFor="let ratingId of ratingArr; index as i"
        [id]="'star_' + i"
        (click)="onClick(i + 1)">
        <mat-icon>{{ rating > i  ? 'star' : 'star_border' }}</mat-icon>
    </button>
    <span>Very Relevant</span>
</ng-container>
```

Tried all sorts of things out in the Chrome inspector, but have made no meaningful progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like that:

```
<div *ngIf="starCount" style="display: flex; align-items: center">
    <span>Not Relevant</span>
    <button
        mat-icon-button
        color="primary"
        *ngFor="let ratingId of ratingArr; index as i"
        [id]="'star_' + i"
        (click)="onClick(i + 1)">
        <mat-icon>{{ rating > i  ? 'star' : 'star_border' }}</mat-icon>
    </button>
    <span>Very Relevant</span>
</div>
```